# How to only show the first x characters of a post as a preview (PHP)?

Tags: php, function

I was wondering how you would show only the first "x" characters of a post, as a preview. Sort of like what StackOverflow does when they show there list of questions.

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

goes to

```
The quick brown fox jumps...
```

I dont want to split up a word in the middle. I was thinking the explode function splitting up at every space , explode(" ", $post), but I wasnt too sure if there was another way or not. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
preg_match('/^.{0,30}(?:.*?)\b/iu', $text, $matches);
```

which will match at most 30 chars, then break at the next nearest word-break

Comment: @Alix - actually on second thoughts, you wouldn't need the grouping at all - `$matches[0]` would be correct no?

Answer (score 2):

strpos ( http://www.php.net/strpos ) will give you what you need.  This function should give you what you need.

```
function getPreview($text, $minimumLength=60){
     return substr($text,0,strpos($text,' ',$minimumLength)) . '...';
}
```

*Note: I haven't tested that function*

Answer (score 1):

Use `strpos()` with an offset to find a conveniently-placed space, and use `substr()` to slice the string there.

Answer (score 1):

you can try [wordwrap](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$x = 14;
$newtext = wordwrap($str, $x);
$s  = explode("\n",$newtext,2);
print $s[0];
```

NB: if $x is say 8, the output will be "The" , not "The quick"

You can also use explode.

```
$str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$s = explode(" ",$str);
$x=14;
$final="";
foreach ($s as $k){
    if ( strlen($final) <= $x ){
        $final.="$k ";
    }else{ break; }
}
print "-> $final\n";
```